# Python code output is displaying in Mimecast mobile application but not in outlook

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to read the content in the file and display that one as in html table format but the out put was showing correctly in "Mimecast" mobile app and not correctly showing in outlook

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib
import teradata
# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import re
import os
import subprocess
import logging
import smtplib,email,email.encoders,email.mime.text,email.mime.base
import getpass
import sys

Loop_to1 = sys.argv[1]
Loop_to = int(Loop_to1)
Month = sys.argv[2]
Day = sys.argv[3]
Year = sys.argv[4]
filename = sys.argv[5]

print(Loop_to)

def email_user():
  smtpserver = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  to = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
  fromAddr = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxx".format(Month = Month,Day = Day,Year = Year)

  # create html email
  emailMsg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  emailMsg['Subject'] = subject
  emailMsg['From'] = fromAddr
  emailMsg['To'] = ', '.join(to)

  #emailMsg['Cc'] = ", ".join(cc)

  emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""

    <html><body>
    <h4>Hi All,  <br><br>
  Please find the below backup job status and all weekly jobs successfully completed <br><br>
  </h4>

    <table border="2">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
               <td>JOB NAME</td>
                           <td>Number Of Objects Backed Up</td>
                           <td>STATUS</td>
                                 <td>Backed Up Date</td>
                                <td>Back up completed Time stamp</td>
        </tr>
    """.format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename), "html", _charset="utf-8"))

  print("""

            1    Testing

  """)

  file1 = open(filename,"r")

  i = 1
  print(Loop_to)
  while i <= Loop_to:
          emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""
          <tr>
          """.format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename), "html", _charset="utf-8"))
          line=file1.readline()
          cont=line.split()
          for info in cont:
                  emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""
                  <td>{info}""".format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename,info = info), "html", _charset="utf-8"))

                  print(info)
                  emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""
                  </td>""".format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename,info = info), "html", _charset="utf-8"))
          emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""
          </tr>""".format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename), "html", _charset="utf-8"))
          print("""

                Testing

          """)
          print(i,Loop_to)
          i += 1


  emailMsg.attach(MIMEText("""
  </table>
  <h4>
  <br><br>
  Thanks,<br>

    </h4>
  </body></html>
      """.format(Day = Day,Month = Month,Year = Year , Loop_to = Loop_to , filename = filename), "html", _charset="utf-8"))
```

Comment: So, what happens in outlook? Can you be more specific about what is going wrong?

Comment: In outlook it displaying the output in html table format up to headers.Hi All, 

Please find the below backup job status and all weekly jobs successfully completed 
JOB NAME Number Of Objects Backed Up STATUS Backed Up Date Back up completed Time stamp